# Using mutate and last functions with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the `last` function in `dplyr` package, if you want to take the last element in a vector, excluding `NA`s, you can just introduce the `na.omit`.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- c(1:10,NA)
last(x)
# [1] NA
last(na.omit(x))
# [1] 10
```

I would like to impute the last element for `var1` for each `id`. The following is an example of the dataframe used.

```
id<-rep(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,2))
var1<-c(5,1,4,2,NA,NA,NA)
df<-data.frame(id,var1)
df
#   id var1
# 1  1    5
# 2  1    1
# 3  1    4
# 4  2    2
# 5  2   NA
# 6  3   NA
# 7  3   NA
```

Notice that `id=1` contains only numeric for `var1`, `id=2` contains one numeric and one `NA`, while `id=3` contains only `NA`s and no numeric.
I would like to obtain the following:

```
df
#   id var1
# 1  1    4
# 2  1    4
# 3  1    4
# 4  2    2
# 5  2    2
# 6  3   NA
# 7  3   NA
```

Here is what I did to achieve what I wanted, but I got an error.

```
mutate(var1=ifelse(length(na.omit(var1))==0,NA,last(na.omit(var1))))
# Error: Unsupported vector type language
```

**EDIT1**: Based on the comments, the above code works well for dplyr 0.4.3, and apparently not for dplyr 0.5.0 (in my case). Additionally, I want to impute using the last element not the element with the maximum value. Thus, I have changed my data frame to make it more general.

**EDIT2**:I have considered a data frame that list all possible cases. Three cases, (1) all numeric, (2) numeric + NAs and (3) all NAs.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on dplyr 0.4.3.

Comment: May I know how do you check the version for the package?

Comment: @HNSKD - I used `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @HNSKD : Use this `packageVersion("dplyr")`

Comment: @thelatemail I'm using dplyr 0.5.0 and got the above-mentioned error. Any suggestion how I can work this thing out?

Comment: @HNSKD - could be a bug - you might have to roll back or wait for it to be fixed - https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1980

Comment: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(var1=na.omit(var1)) %>% mutate(var1=last(var1))` works for you?

Comment: I'm also having the same error and my dplyr was recently updated. My code worked fine before, but not on 0.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I was asked to explain my solution, but I actually don't fully understand why OP's solution doesn't work. Initially I thought it was something due to the class of object returned by `na.omit`

```
> na.omit(var1)
[1] 1 2 3 4
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 5
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

But then I noticed that `nth` (and I think `last` is just a wrapper for it) works fine:

```
df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(var1=nth(na.omit(var1),-1L))
```

An alternative, is to use `tail` rather then `last`

```
df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(var1=tail(na.omit(var1),1))
```

Or to create a new function, as I initially did:

```
aa <- function(x) last(na.omit(x))
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(var1=aa(var1))
```

I was just curious about any differences in performance, so I checked them out but I would say they are equivalent

```
Unit: microseconds
                                          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq        max neval
mutate(var1 = nth(na.omit(var1), -1L)) 795.270 830.4880 1022.196 897.6375 1026.795   4437.483  1000
mutate(var1 = tail(na.omit(var1)))     791.035 825.6165 1011.288 892.6270 1037.463   3406.842  1000
mutate(var1 = aa(var1))                788.085 825.5180 1108.872 888.9945 1036.664 102915.926  1000
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to also provide an explanation for this code.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen This is all I can do, hopefully somebody else will be able to make more sense of why the OP's solution doesn't work.

Comment: @HNSKD I am a bit confused...does this work on you original dataset? `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(var1=nth(var1,-1L))`. If you omit NAs -and there were originally only NAs associated to that ID -then the script doesn't know what "last" element to pick. But if you keep them...then what was the issue originally that you have to do `na.omit`? I actually forgot. Also, you edited the output but the code you have doesn't match.

Comment: Hi @Dambo, sincere apologies for the confusion. I have edited the question again and the dataframe includes all 3 cases. Apparently, last function cannot work, but the tail and nth functions works perfectly.

Comment: @HNSKD You mean the first two once `na.omit` is removed, right? If yes, we are actually back to the example you posted at the beginning when you said that `last` wasn't working as expected for you...

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr package, we can group by each id and take max values of each id and replace in var1

```
library(dplyr)

    df <- df %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      mutate(var1 = max(var1,na.rm=T))

    df
         id  var1
      <dbl> <int>
    1     1     3
    2     1     3
    3     1     3
    4     2     4
    5     2     4
```

Comment: @ChristianJonassen Using dplyr package we can group by each id and take max values of each id and replace in var1

Comment: This works only as long as var1 is ordered and numeric tho (which could well be all OP needs actually)

Comment: I have edited my question, specifically the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. This worked for me:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(missing = is.na(var1)) %>%
  mutate(var1 = ifelse(any(!missing), var1[!missing][length(var1[!missing])], NA))
```